# Java exception running function listEmployee(): java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to java and I can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong, it's properly something really basic, I want to be able to add information about employees and then then display/list that data (id, first name, last name, salary, position etc ) using a menu() method.

Everything compiles and adding employee information with addEmployee() seems to work fine but when running listEmployees() I get the exception: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException.

I have been playing around with it for a bit but I'm not getting anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee
{
  final static int MAX=20;
  static int [] idArray= new int[MAX];
  static String [] firstnameArray= new String[MAX];
  static String [] lastnameArray= new String[MAX];
  static int count=0;

  public static void add(int id, String fname, String lname)
  {
    idArray[count] = id;
    firstnameArray[count] = fname; 
    lastnameArray[count] = lname; 
    ++count;
  }

  public static void addEmployee()
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);      
    for(int i=0; i<idArray.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter your id as an integer");
      System.out.print("  (0 to finish): ");
      int id = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      if (id==0)E
        return;

      System.out.println("Enter your First name");

      String fname = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter your Last name");

      String lname = sc.nextLine();

      add(id, fname, lname);
    }
  }

  public static void listEmployees()
  {
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
      System.out.printf("%-15s %10d \n",idArray[i],firstnameArray[i],lastnameArray[i] );
    }
  }

  public static void printMenu()     
  {
     System.out.println
     (
       "\n         ==Menu==\n" +
       "1. Add Employee\n"+
       "2. Display Employee\n"+                    
       "3. Quit\n"
     );   
  }

  public static void menu()
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int option = 0;    
    while(option!=3)
    {
      printMenu();
      System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
      option = input.nextInt();
      switch(option)
      {
        case 1:   
          addEmployee(); 
          break;
        case 2:   
          listEmployees();    
          break;
        case 3:
          break;
        default: 
          System.out.println("Wrong option");
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    menu();
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%-15s %10d \n"...` Your format codes need to match the arguments. You are passing "int, string, string", but your format string says "string, int". You want something like: `System.out.printf("%10d %-15s %-15s\n", idArray[i],firstnameArray[i],lastnameArray[i])`.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. The majority of your code is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string (lastnameArray[i]) to a numeric format (%10d). You need to first convert the string lastnameArray[i] to an int/long and then pass that value to %10d.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println(idArray[i] + " " + firstnameArray[i] + " " + lastnameArray[i]);
```

use this one instaed of your printing statement

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function has the wrong arguments passed to it. You should match the format and parameters passed to print them in the same order. Assuming you are passing the correct parameter to be printed, the first parameter should have `%d , %s , %s` respectively.